# Why is this function is $O(x^n)$

Tags: combinatorics, taylor-expansion

$$f(x) = \prod_{k=0}^{n} (1+kx)^{ (-1)^k \binom {n} {k} }$$

How to prove that Taylor expansion of this function at zero stars from 1 and then $c x^n$ (all intermidiat terms are zero)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the coeffients of $x^j$, $1\leq j\leq n-1$ are $0$, in fact, as $f(0)=1$.

Let $\tau=x\frac{d}{dx}$. For $0\leq j\leq n-1$, We have

$$\tau^j((1-x)^n))=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k{n \choose k}k^j x^k$$

Now by an easy induction, $\tau^j((1-x^n)=(1-x)^{n-j}A_j(x)$ for some polynomial $A_j$, hence if we put $x=1$, this gives for $0\leq j\leq n-1$:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k{n \choose k}k^j =0$$

Now 
$$\log f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k{n\choose k}\log (1+kx)$$

Hence  the coefficient of $x^j$ , $j\leq j\leq n-1$ in $\log f(x)$ is

$$\frac{(-1)^{j-1}}{j}(\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k{n \choose k}k^j) =0 $$

And $\log (f(x))=O(x^n)$. It is easy to finish.

Comment: It is funny that to prove statment about taylor series you reformulated it as an equality with binomial coeffisiants and then actually derived it from taylor expansion of another function (after change of variables your $\tau$ becomes just usual derivation). I have to think, is it possible to pass directly from one function to another.

Answer (score 0):

The claim is false.  For $n=1$, $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x} = 1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots$.

In fact, I don't see any challenge to showing that the Taylor expansion around $0$ of these functions all start with "$1 - x^n + \cdots$".  So the zeroeth order term is always $1$.

Comment: The question has been edited.